# How to post data from DOM to nodejs via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I use POST method to send JSON data to the URL and I am utilizing from this data in order to render the page and I am rendering page via underscorejs. Is there any way to retrieve that data (in JSON format) and assigned them in another var in AJAX and send it as a data ?

I am trying to send data to the nodejs server in order to update Mongo DB. But there is no luck...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addContact").click(function(){
        var responseArea = $('.actionArea');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/account/:id/added',
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false, 
            data: { contactId: this.model.get('_id') },
            function onSuccess() {
                $responseArea.text('Contact Added');
            }, function onError() {
                $responseArea.text('Could not add contact'); 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The error I am getting "Cannot call method 'get' of undefined"

Comment: What is `this.model`?

Comment: That means that the 'this.model' is not defined.

Comment: I render the page "res.render(URL,{model : users..})..." so, i guess I defined it. Am i wrong?

Comment: That variable is for the server-side template and has nothing to do with `this.model` here, in which `model` is expected to be a property of the `#addContact` element, which it is not.  I think you're getting a little mixed up between the server/client code.  Furthermore `/account/:id/aded` looks like a route mapping, not a URL.

Comment: @numbers1311407, yeap you are right. I just read couple of tutorials, and I understood my mistake, thank you !